# reattach a deleted file to a directory

Tags: c, linux

Is it possible for a program to reattach a file to the file system tree that has been deleted but to which it still has an open file descriptor?

i.e. if a program has done

```
int fd = open("/dir/myfile", O_RDONLY);
unlink("/dir/myfile");
```

does there exist anything like

```
linkfd(fd, "myfile", "/otherdir/");
```

that will create `/otherdir/myfile` as an entry to the same file that used to be at `/dir/myfile`?

I know it is possible to recover the *content* of such a deleted-but-still-open file through `/proc/<PID>/fd/<num>`, but that creates a new file with a different inode number. I want to know if it is possible to reattach the *same* file, so that `/otherdir/myfile` has the same inode number that the deleted `/dir/myfile` had.

Comment: No Linux filesystem driver does this at the moment. Theoretically, it'd be conceivable to e.g. create an `ioctl()` that you'd use on a filedescriptor obtained by opening `/proc/<PID>/fd/<num>` to "re-reference" / in-place re-create the file. No standard (IEEE 1003.1 / POSIX) interface to do such exists, though, and whether this can be made to work at all ultimately depends on how the underlaying filesystem implements deletes. Pure log-structured fs may never allow it.

Comment: @FrankH. "Pure log-structured fs may never allow it." - I don't think so. The file exists at least as long as `fd` is open and is not yet deleted. And until then, it should be possible to link it to another file.

Comment: @glglgl: Nope. The implementation can choose to pre-delete the blocks on disk and simply keep an in-memory reference that prevents re-allocation of the same (till the ref drops to zero). In this case, on-disk state is gone (irrecoverably) while in-core state persists. Whether this happens or not is simply an implementation choice of the filesystem itself.

Comment: Same as for the data associated with the inode goes for the inode itself; there is nothing that prevents a filesystem implementation from e.g. maintaining inode numbers combined with "generation numbers", where you can re-use a deleted inode even while there are still processes holding that open; old users (preceding current gen) would use in-memory state, while new users (current gen) would get (and be able to modify) the on-disk inode.

Comment: @FrankH. I think the behaviour you refer to is what happens *after* all references INCLUDING the open files are gone. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/unlink.html clearly states that "When the file's link count becomes 0 and no process has the file open, the space occupied by the file shall be freed and the file shall no longer be accessible. If one or more processes have the file open when the last link is removed, the link shall be removed before unlink() returns, but the removal of the file contents shall be postponed until all references to the file are closed."

Comment: So what you count as "ref dropping to zero" is the file's link count plus the number of open files. (For big files larger than your RAM the behaviour you describe would be impossible. And it is definitely possible to fully use an open file until you `close()` it. Only then it may be removed from disk.)

Comment: @glglgl: very aware of the OpenGroup document - if you read it carefully, it does _not_ state _anything whatsoever_ about how exactly access to the file contents is being maintained during the "window" between someone calling `unlink()` and the time of last close. All it says that the freeing the space / removing the contents is deferred. The _file contents_ will not / cannot be memory cached for large files, but any information _how to actually locate these file contents_ (this is _not_ spec'ed - it's an implementation detail) _can_ be (and often is). Your on-disk state may be _ahead_.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, if it has been deleted, it doesn't have an inode any more. A file might be considered to be not the contents, but the directory entry, and that's gone.

As you say, the content hasn't been lost, yet, but the inode is unrecoverable.

Comment: You're wrong. The inode is deleted only when there are no more references to it in POSIX semantics, and the open fd counts as a reference. There's still no API to create a new hardlink to it, though.

Comment: @cha0site: If one could downvote comments I would; all POSIX guarantees is that _for the process having the file open_, access to it is not lost if said file is deleted by another process. That does _not mandate_, for example, a behaviour where you powercycle the machine in this situation, reboot and _still have the file_ (after all, it was open by someone when you pressed the power button). Persistence guarantee affects in-memory state only.

Comment: @FrankH.: I have no idea what you're on about. The [POSIX unlink specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html) says basically what I was saying, reference counting semantics and all. I think you might be confusing the inode with the link (that is, the name of the file?)

Comment: @cha0site: All the POSIX spec says "the removal of the file contents shall be postponed". That means nothing else but what I've said - they're put on deathrow. Dropping of the last reference in this case can actually happen via recovery-after-reboot, for example - but in any case, the _inode_ goes earlier than the data blocks / file contents associated with it, which discards (potentially all) persistent (on disk) reference to the data.

Comment: @FrankH.: No, the *link* goes earlier than the file contents. The *inode* stays. If it doesn't stay, then how is the following consistent: `open(2)` a file (you get an fd back), `unlink(2)` that file (lets assume that was the sole hardlink). Now, `fstat(2)` the fd you got earlier. In the `struct stat` you get back, you have an inode number. It also has the user id and group id information that is only present in the inode.

Comment: Interesting discussion. I think it's entirely academic though: my answer is practically correct, even if I used the wrong words. Instead of "it doesn't have an inode any more", read "the inode cannot be relinked".

Comment: @cha0site: The "_inode_" as in "in-memory data structure" stays, that's correct. The same goes for whatever the block allocation handle(s) are - their in-memory equivalents stay. _Nothing_ is guaranteed about the corresponding on-disk state beyond the data not being overwritten until either reboot or "final close" happens. Also note that `inode_t` (inode _numbers_ as returned by `[f]stat()`) can be purely synthetic information - not all filesystems maintain this as a number on disk (FAT, for example, does not).

Comment: @FrankH.: OK, from where I stand that's the same thing. The "on-disk" vs. "in-memory" dichotomy was introduced by you - we agree that the in-memory inode struct must remain, and it could conceivably be later written back to disk. Of course, POSIX does not provide such a facility. FAT is a bad example, as it's not a POSIX file-system.

Comment: @ams: I didn't downvote your answer, because it has an essence of truth behind it, but it completely fails to account for the UNIX file semantics.